# How this deadlock happens in Scala Future?

Tags: multithreading, scala, asynchronous, future

This snippet is excerpted from [Monix document](https://monix.io/docs/3x/best-practices/blocking.html#if-blocking-use-scalas-blockcontext).
It's an example that how to enter deadlock in Scala.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent._
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))

def addOne(x: Int) = Future(x + 1)

def multiply(x: Int, y: Int) = Future {
  val a = addOne(x)
  val b = addOne(y)
  val result = for (r1 <- a; r2 <- b) yield r1 * r2

  // This can dead-lock due to the limited size of our thread-pool!
  Await.result(result, Duration.Inf)
}
```

I understand what the code does, but not about how it executed.

Why it is the line `Await.result(result, Duration.Inf)` causing the deadlock ? (Yes, I tested it)

Is not that the outermost `Future` at multiply function occupy all the thread pool(the single one) and thus deadlock (because the addOne future is forever blocked on waiting for thread)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is not that the outermost Future at multiply function occupy all the thread pool(the single one) and thus deadlock (because the addOne future is forever blocked on waiting for thread)?

Yes, sort of.

When you call `val a = addOne(x)`, you create a new Future that starts waiting for a thread. However, as you noted, the only thread is currently in use by the outermost Future. That wouldn't be a problem without await, since Futures are able to handle this condition. However, this line:

```
Await.result(result, Duration.Inf)
```

causes the outer Future to wait for the `result` Future, which can't run because the outer Future is still using the only available thread. (And, of course, it also can't run because the `a` and `b` Futures can't run, again due to the outer Future.)

Here's a simpler example that also deadlocks without creating so many Futures:

```
def addTwo(x: Int) = Future {
  Await.result(addOne(x + 1), Duration.Inf)
}
```

Comment: why `def addTwo(x: Int) = Future {addOne(x + 1)}` works ?
res5: Future[Future[Int]] = Future(Success(Future(Success(3)))), it has 2 Futures, it should've exhausted all threads.

Comment: @WeiChingLin Because you didn't ask it for the results of one in the other (via `Await.result`), so it didn't need to evaluate them both at once.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would say ***this code can simulate deadlock, it’s not guaranteed that it will always be in the deadlock.*** 
What is happening in the above code. We have only a single thread in the thread pool. And as soon as we are calling the multiple function as it’s the future so it should run on a separate thread say we assign the single thread we have in the thread pool to this function. 
Now the function addOne also is a future so it will again start running on the same thread, but will not wait for a=addOne to get complete and move to the next line b=addOne hence the same thread which was executing the a=addOne now executing the b=addOne and the value of all will never be calculated and that future is not complete and never going to be complete as we have only one thread, same case with the line b=addOne it control will not wait to complete that future and move to the for loop for is also async in the Scala so it will again not evaluated and move to the last line await and it will be waiting for the infinity amount of time to complete the previous futures.

**Necessary and sufficient condition to get into the dead lock.**

1. Mutual Exclusion Condition
2. Hold and Wait Condition
3. No-Preemptive Condition
4. Circular Wait Condition

Here we can see we have only one thread so the processes going to be execute are not mutually exclusive.

once the thread is executing specific block and hence it’s a future and not waiting to complete it, it’s going ahead and executing the next block hence it’s reaching to the await statement and the thread is holding there while all the other future which are not complete are waiting for the thread to complete the future.

Once the thread is allocated to the await it can’t be preempt that’s the reason we can’t execute the remaining future which are not complete.

And circular wait is there because awaits is waiting for the non-complete future to be complete and other futures are waiting for the await call to be complete.

Simply we can say the control will directly reach to the await statement and start waiting for the non-complete futures to got complete which is not going to be happen anyhow. Because we have only one thread in our thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

```
Await.result(result, Duration.Inf)
```

When you use `await`, you are waiting for future to complete. And you have given infinite time. So if anyhow Future will never be able to complete, main thread go to infinite wait.